# Converting a series to a recursive expression

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let $e_i$ be a unit vector with one 1 in the $i$-th element. Is the following expression has a recursive presentation?

$$y = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\frac{{{X^k} e_i}}{\|{{{X^k} e_i}\|}_2}} $$

where $X$ is a $n \times n$ square matrix, and ${\| \cdot \|}_2$ is a vector norm defined as ${\|z\|}_2 = \sqrt{|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2+...+|z_n|^2}$.

---

EDIT: I know that if $y = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {{X^k} e_i} $, it is easy to obtain the following recursive formula:

$$y_{k+1} = X y_{k} + e_i, \quad (k=0,1,2,...) \textrm{ with } \ \ \ y_0=e_i$$

However, after we add a normalized factor, is there a similar recursive expression? Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a particular kind of recursive expression, i.e., with only first powers of $X$?

Comment: I am actually looking for a recursive equation in terms of $y$ whose solution is an infinite series $y=\sum_{k \ge 0} {\frac{X^k e_i}{{\|X^k e_i\|}_2}}$.